# Geocode API query limit exceed

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

Geocode API allowed 2500 requests per day, but my site is not sending such requests in a single day. is my code sending automated requests?

```
function getmap($addrss,$location,$city){

$address = $addrss.' '.$city.' '.$location;
$prepAddr = urlencode($address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
$retval = $lat.'*'.$long;
return $retval;
```

}

**Response came**

*[error_message] => You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.....[status] => OVER_QUERY_LIMIT )*

Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: To know if your code is sending automated requests, you'd need to know what calls the `getmap()` function.

Comment: Its simple a function calling once from front page, its not in any loop.

Comment: Are you using shared hosting? It is possible someone else is also using the Geocoding API.

Comment: No its totally dedicated server. is my code correct ?

Comment: `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` is due to maximum request per second is exceeded, use setTimeout of 100 or 200 ms after each request..

Comment: But my page is not sending such amount of requests. but still i'll use settimeout, should delay() will work as code is in php.

Comment: Or should i use sleep() ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [API Example I've looked up](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#geocoding-request-and-response-latitudelongitude-lookup) it specifically requests appending the API Key to the request URL, might that be it? Otherwise my guess would be accidental looped requests.

It would be best if the API Key was set outside this function in case other functions in this class / object want to access the API as well.

```
$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false&key='.$API_KEY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use google browser key as below in order to get more number of requests per day

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_MAP_API_KEY&address=los+Angels

Follow these steps to get GOOGLE API KEY,

1. Go to the Google Developers Console.
2. Create or select a project.
3. Click Continue to enable the API and any related services.
4. On the Credentials page, get a Browser key (and set the API
   Credentials).
5. (Optional) Enable billing.

Note: If you have an existing Browser key, you may use that key.
To prevent quota theft, secure your API key following these best practices.

Comment: from 5th option it seems that i need to pay there. but is it free for 2500 requests ?

Comment: pls check below link for more details :https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage#standard-usage-limits

Comment: it shows error and says "Browser API keys cannot have referer restrictions when used with this API....REQUEST_DENIED"

Comment: i chose Google Maps Embed API for Web.

Comment: try again by leaving  'Accept requests from these HTTP referrers (web sites) ' as optional